# union two collections in mongodb with one query

Tags: php, mongodb

I have one collection named USER

```
{"_id" => "id1", ...}
```

and another collection named CONTACT

```
{"_id" => "id2", ...}
```

now i have an array

```
[id1, id2]
```

Can I get two data with one query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Aggregation Framework [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operator for that.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { id1:1, id2: 1, allValues: { $setUnion: [ "$id1", "$id2" ] } } }
   ]
)
```